# Changing color of svg path

Tags: css, svg, colors, path

I create this SVG file and inside that there is a path called with the ID "prova" (check it with firebug, it's the red tooth)
http://studiodentisticocova.com/Psicologia-funzionale_03_provasvg.svg

The question is, how can i change the colour of that path? In CSS or jQuery because I would make an "Hover" over it! I tried in many ways but I wasn't able.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is a specificity issue

```
#prova:hover {
fill: yourcolorhere;
}
```

should work.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/r8uqb/)